# Redirect to another controller with a Flash message - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, exception, cakephp, components, cakephp-3.0

There's a way to redirect from a component to a different controller (not the one who called the component) with a Flash message? Something like:

```
namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;

class ValidateValueComponent extends Component
{
    public function validateValue($var = null){
        try{
            if(!$var){
                throw new \Exception();
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            $action = $this->request->params['action'] === 'index' ? 'home' : $this->request->params['action'];
            $controller = $action === 'home' ? 'Home' : $this->request->params['controller'];

            $this->_registry->getController()->Flash->error(__('Message!'));
            // $this->_registry->getController()->redirect(['controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to validate some values and avoid it to break the execution. If there are no value (not empty) on the $var I want to check if the error was called by the index method, if so send the user to the home page (HomeController) with the flash message. In the other case just send the user to the index from the controller who captured the error and show the flash message.

This code above allow me to show the Flash or redirect, but I cannot do both of them.

Anyway,

Thank you all!

Comment: Correcting, where I wrote no value (not empty) I mean empty..

Comment: Persisting flash messages across redirects requires use of the session, so make sure that your session works, ie check that the session cookie is being set/sent. Also check your debug/error logs for possible problems regarding headers.

Comment: Do you have some reference code or use example? I'll search for that.

Comment: You said that you can show the Flash message sometimes, so your session is presumably fine. I'm surprised that the code you're showing could ever accomplish a redirect, though, as that's generally done by returning a redirect request from the controller action; you're not returning the redirect here, and you're not in the controller action.

Comment: Ops, forgot about the return.. anyway, since that you already helping me out do you know if there's a way to use the $this->redirect with a prefix? Using the options array or something like that.. thanks

Comment: I managed it out using the request to find the URL prefix and redirected accordly, if you have others ideas or ways to make it I would appreciate to learn it as well. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved using this link from [bookstack.cn](https://www.bookstack.cn/read/cakephp-4.x/181361) but overwall I needed to call the Flash component on my $components array and then use it normally, independant of the controller who has called the component. Something like:

```
namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;

class ValidateValueComponent extends Component
{
    public $components = ['Flash'];

    public function validateValue($var = null){
        try{
            if(!$var){
                throw new \Exception();
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            $action = $this->request->params['action'] === 'index' ? 'home' : $this->request->params['action'];
            $controller = $action === 'home' ? 'Home' : $this->request->params['controller'];

            $this->Flash->set(__('Message!'));
            return $this->_registry->getController()->redirect(['controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action]);
        }
    }
}
```